# get value with button

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I just want to get the value from a textfield with a button. I have this:

```
// Add extra contact clicked?
$('#add-contact p a').click(function(e) {
  console.log('hallo');
  var emailValue = $("input#contactpersonen-email").val();
  console.log(emailValue);

  // Make a copy of the first input fields
  html = $('#new-contact').children().clone();
  //$("#contactpersonen-email").val($("#contactpersonen-email1").val());  


  // Get number of tabs in the accordion
  var index = $('#accordion h3').length;

  // Remove the values
  html.find("input[type=text]").val("");
  html.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);

  // New 'id', 'for' and 'name' attribute names
  html.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {


    me = $(this);
    attr = me.attr('id');
    number = attr.split('_')[2];
    newNumber = parseInt(index) + 1;
    newAttr = attr.replace(number, newNumber);
    me.attr('id', newAttr).attr('name', newAttr).next().attr('for', newAttr);

  });

  // Insert it at the end

  $('#accordion').append(html);
  $('#accordion').accordion('refresh');

  // Set last tab to active
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    active: index
  });

  // Cancel the click
  return false;
});
```

So I do just this:

```
var emailValue = $("input#contactpersonen-email").val();
                                    console.log(emailValue);
```

and this is the html:

```
<div class="contact-label span2">
  <label for="contactpersonen-email">Email adres</label>
  <div class="contact-input-field">
    <input type="text" class="input-text span2 required contactpersonen_email" id="contactpersonen_email" name="contactpersonen_email"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

but every time I get undefined back?? So how to get the value then? I don't understand

Thank you

Comment: You use `contactpersonen-email` in your selector but  the ID is `contactpersonen_email`

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your comment. You should post your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo. This should work:

```
$(function() {
  var emailValue = $("#contactpersonen_email").val();
  console.log(emailValue);
});
```

Comment: thank you. But I the click function is already in the function the click function is in the $(document).ready(function()
       {

Comment: ah. I get it. Thank you. Nice

Comment: Ah I see. Did you see @Turnip comment above about you using a hyphen instead of an underscore? You should be using `_email` instead of `-email`. Or change them both to be hyphens.